# Angular 4 - Read the rules by name from scss file

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I Need to extract a rule by class selector from .scss file, to show on the Angular app ui, but so far could not find a good parser for .scss that I can use for just fetching a class rule by name.

Example: If I pass class selector name= 'custom-class', I need the content in brackets, simple.

```
.custom-class {
   width: 334px;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Is there typings for scss that can be used? or any npm packages that can be used where I can give the file path and the class name for which the rule content has to be read from from the scss file? 
Example for listing the class selectors(https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-css-selectors) there is a npm package(but for css file), but not finding one where it can fetch the class content from scss file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access .scss files from your application runtime because they processed to css files. You can try to list all style sheets loaded by browser to find necessary class.

```
for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
  const sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
  if (sheet['cssRules']) {
    for (const rule of sheet['cssRules']) {
      const cssText = rule['cssText'] as string;
      if (cssText.startsWith('.my-class')) {
        console.log(cssText);
      }
    }
  }
}
// Console output:
// .my-class { color: rgb(51, 51, 51); }
```

Comment: @Vinc  can you upvote or accept my answer if it was usefull.

Comment: thanks for your reply Dmitriy, even before the styles come to the browser, I have to fetch, so currently going with the approach of showing in the UI CSS instead of SCSS, I found this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssparser, which gives the JSON format of the CSS file, please suggest if there is a better/efficient solution that this?